# How to open then close "Devices and Printers" folder using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, controls, panel

So I am writing a powershell script to install all of the printers in my office.

But first, I want it to open the Devices and Printers Folder.
Then, after all the printers have been installed, I want it to close that folder.

When I go to the control panel, I can make a shortcut to Devices and Printers on my desktop.
The lnk points to "Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers".

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: what do you mean with _open_? Do you want it to open in explorer?

Comment: Yes, I would like it to open in Explorer exactly as if you clicked "Start" and clicked "Devices and Printers" (on Win7).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To open it, you can type

```
PS> control printers
```

To close it, you can use a COM object to control the shell

```
(New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).Windows() | 
where-object {$_.LocationName -eq "Devices and Printers"} | 
foreach-object {$_.quit()}
```

Comment: I couldn't use stop-process because it was running through explorer.